# Error when using file from classpath in XWPFDocument

Tags: java

When I try to use a docx file I have in my src/Default.docx, It won't let me use it for the XWPFDocument. The docx file is even part of my build path. I'm using POI API, and have all external jars installed correctly. (This works If I use a path to my desktop instead of classpath)

```
InputStream file = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Default.docx");
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(file);
```

Gives me:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: in is null
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.<init>(ZipInputStream.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:83)
at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:267)
at org.apache.poi.util.PackageHelper.open(PackageHelper.java:39)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:120)
at thompsons.printer.Format.<init>(Format.java:15)
at thompsons.printer.Printer.print(Printer.java:15)
at thompsons.ui.MainPanel$3.actionPerformed(MainPanel.java:238)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Comment: test the path of `file`, check if it is inside a jar file

Comment: that could be the problem, can you confirm whether the file exists in the jar file